# Swapping fadein with slide horizontally in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I am using the following script for an animated background, right now the pictures fadein and fadeout but I want them to slide, horizontally, to the left.

My question is, is this a standard jquery "function" because I have trouble finding the proper way to do this.

Is anyone able to help me modify my code so it does what I want it to do?

Thanks in advance.

Code I'm using:

```
$(function(){
    $('#background img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('#background :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('#background');}, 
      3000);
});
```

Comment: slide `vertically` to the left? Do you mean horizontally?

Comment: @Jean-Paul ... yes horizontally, I feel so stupid now

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery `.animate()` to toggle horizontally. For example:

```
$('#background :first-child').animate({width: 'toggle'})
     .next('img').animate({width: 'toggle'})
     .end().appendTo('#background');}, 
  3000);
```